# SQL MAX COUNT & MIN COUNT

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying these two SQL statements on the following two tables:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    Country
FROM (
    SELECT
        customer.country,
        count(*) as Appointments
    FROM        
       customer.country  
    GROUP BY 
        country
    ORDER BY 
        count(*) 
) AS AppointmentCount
```

The SQL above is supposed to give the country with maximum appointments through COUNT (For the MIN I was going to use ORDER BY DESC)

[tables' image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15zUK.jpg)

Unfortunately the above SQL is giving the following error but I cannot find a way to fix it:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1 Country FROM ( SELECT customer.country, count(*)' at line 1

Any help on how I can gix the above SQL statement? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is 2 issues : mysql => Not TOP but LIMIT and the Table Name is customer not customer.country

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `TOP` statement, that is for MSSQL. You need to use a `LIMIT` instead. Try this one:

```
SELECT
    Country
FROM (
    SELECT
        customer.country,
        count(*) as Appointments
    FROM        
       customer
    GROUP BY 
        country
) AS AppointmentCount
ORDER BY
    Appointments DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a minor problem. You need to fix the `FROM` clause. I.e. `customer.country` is not a table. This will be right:

```
FROM        
   customer
```

Also, the `TOP` is not really compatible with the subquery. Luckily, you don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT
     TOP 1  customer.country
FROM        
   customer
GROUP BY 
    country
ORDER BY 
    count(*)
```

Comment: This still won't work. `TOP` is not supported in MariaDB. But you are correct about not needing the subquery.

Comment: Oh, so it's mariadb :) Then indeed, `LIMIT` can do the same.